# How can I mimic this revolving text animation for my e-commerce store?

Tags: animation, shopify, css-animations, jquery-animate

I'd like to use the text animation found on the Janji.com homepage (Shopify store), near the bottom above the footer.

The text says:
Equipping you for the [ journey ] ahead.

And "journey" is a list item that cycles between several other words.

I'm unable to find out how to do this online in a way similar to this. Ideally it'd be javascript or something lighter than copy-pasting a hundred lines of CSS into my store. Is there some sort of library I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.prop-wrapper.vert-scroll {
    color: #0064a5;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 3%;
}
.tickerv-wrap {
    background: 0 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 12.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tickerv-wrap ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    animation-name: tickerv;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,0);
}
.tickerv-wrap ul li {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #0064a5;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0;
}
@keyframes tickerv{
0%{margin-top:0}25%{margin-top:-50px}50%{margin-top:-100px}75%{margin-top:-150px}100%{margin-top:0}}.tickerv-wrap ul{padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;animation-name:tickerv;animation-duration:10s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(1,0,0.5,0)}.tickerv-wrap ul:hover{animation-play-state:paused}
```

```html
After checking the code on the website, 
I found this done using the CSS code and you can use the bellow code and implement it on any website.
<div class="prop-wrapper vert-scroll" style="max-width: 1500px; margin:auto;">
  Equipping you for the [
  <div class="tickerv-wrap"><ul>
  <li>path</li>
  <li>trail</li>
  <li>road</li>
  <li>journey</li>
</ul></div>
  ] ahead
</div>
```